# vbscript How do I find "-" in a string and place characters that follow in a new string?

Tags: vbscript

I'm using vbscript, how do I find the hyphen character "-" in a string and place characters that follow in a new string?

Basically my computer names end with a room number

PC1-3 (room 3) , PC1-4 (room 4) etc

I'm using

```
Dim roomArray(2)
roomArray = Array("-1", "-2", "-3")

Dim item
For each item in roomArray
 If instr(strComputerName, item)
   ..do something
 End If
Next
```

but I'm getting false positives due to room -33 containing "-3" etc so if I locate "-" in the string and place the characters that follow into a string I can check against the full string rather than using instr.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get all text behind the last hyphen found:

```
Function GetRoomNumber(strComputerName)
    Dim hyphenIndex

    hyphenIndex = InStrRev(strComputerName, "-")
    If hyphenIndex > 0 Then
      GetRoomNumber = Mid(strComputerName, hyphenIndex+1)
    End If
End Function
```

Usage in your example will be:

```
Dim roomArray(2)
roomArray = Array("-1", "-2", "-3")

Dim item, index

For index = LBound(roomArray) To UBound(roomArray)
 item = roomArray(index)
 If ("-" & GetRoomNumber(strComputerName)) = item Then
   ..do something
 End If
Next
```

Or the short version would be (without defining the function with data validation):

```
...
If Mid(strComputerName, InStrRev(strComputerName, "-") ) = item Then
...
```

Comment: Hi awe, thanks for your work. I'm having problems as 'item' seems to be empty. Why can't I use MsgBox(item)? It shows an empty message box. Thanks

Dim item
For each item in roomArray
 MsgBox(item)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if strComputerName ends with dash-roomNumber.

```
if Right(strComputerName,Len(item))=item Then...
```

Answer (score 1):

You kan use right and instr to retrieve this

```
dim s

s = "PC1-3 (room 3)"

msgbox right(s, len(s) - instr(s,"-"))
```